# How to use variables in django url path?

Tags: arrays, django, python-3.x

I am developing and Django website, and I have an array of some str values(parts of url).When user is redirect to:
`https://www.example.com/something/name/`
how can system system knows that that is part of that arry.

I alredy have this:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path(r'<name1>, views.example')
]
```

And Array:

```
arr = [name1,name2,name3, ....namen]  # elements of array are assigned to variables in for loop.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to change urlpatterns to:

```
path('<str:name>,views.example)
```

str is data type, and other data type for this use are:

```
int – Matches zero or any positive integer.
str – Matches any non-empty string, excluding the path separator(‘/’).
slug – Matches any slug string, i.e. a string consisting of alphabets, digits, hyphen and under score.
uuid – Matches a UUID(universal unique identifier).
```

And function call to:

```
views.example(request, name = "name_n") # for better code reading use name_1, name_2, .. name_n instead of name1,name2 etc.
```

and that would be it, enjoy in Django.

Comment: There is also a path type:
path -- Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than a segment of a URL path as with str.

As seen here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters